# Can "equivalent" and "counterpart" be interchangeable in the context below?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

"Between 30 and 40 per cent of children attending school A had problems in the areas of spelling, listening, articulation and concentration in classes, while the *equivalent/counterpart* figures for school B stood at between 5 and 15 per cent."

I wonder if the two words "equivalent" and "counterpart" are interchangeable to each other here in the context as I checked up on the dictionary that the two words both means having same purpose or value as something else does.

Comment: “Corresponding figures” might work.

Answer (score 1):

No, they aren't interchangeable here. Neither of them work. *Equivalent* is an error and *counterpart* is being used in a nonidiomatic way, although the general sense of the word is appropriate to the sentence's objective. BoldBen's answer handles the *counterpart* issue.

*Equivalent* is used when establishing a comparison, not when establishing a contrast. So you can say

> The test scores had different distributions—a score of 80 on test A being equivalent to an 83 on test B.

Here you are establishing differently-valued numbers as equivalent statistics.

Equivalence is about establishing interchangeability between easily distinguishable things. 1/2 and 2/4 are equivalent fractions. It doesn't work with contrasts because contrasting items are not interchangeable.

In a related question [Equal vs equivalent ...](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/317782/equal-vs-equivalent-finer-differences-in-meaning-and-usage-in-4-distinct-scena), John Lawler wrote in a comment

> ... whereas equivalent means 'is a satisfactory substitute for'. And
> substitution requires a context.

Clearly, in the example statement, *satisfactory substitute for* is not the context.

Answer (score 0):

The phrase *equivalent figures* is fairly common.

However, while the phrase *counterpart figures* is syntactically possible, I'd say it's so unusual that it's not something that should be considered if you want to sound natural.

[Google Ngram Viewer](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=equivalent%20figures%2Ccounterpart%20figures&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cequivalent%20figures%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccounterpart%20figures%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cequivalent%20figures%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccounterpart%20figures%3B%2Cc0) indicates that *counterpart figures* is much less common—and it almost flatlines at the bottom of the usage chart, with only a slight increase around 1980 for some reason.

[image: equivalent figures versus counterpart figures]

In short, keep to *equivalent* in this phrase and context.

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you so much for the prompt and detailed answer, especially with the line graph.

Comment: @WilliamSong Your comment made me realize I'd forgotten to provide a link to that chart in my answer. I've updated it. ;)

Comment: With all due respect for descriptivists, the fact that the phrase *equivalent figures* is more frequent does not automatically entail that it is the best, clearest expression to use, and that its alternatives are to be avoided. Given that the figures are, in fact, different, there is something odd about saying that they are equivalent (i.e. equal), notwithstanding the frequency of the expression. The alternatives, such as *counterpart figures, analogous figures,* and *corresponding figures*, avoid that oddness.

Comment: @jsw29 [Equivalence](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/equivalent) has several senses, and not all of them mean *exactly equal*. For instance, one sense, which seems quite applicable here, is "having the same solution set" and "capable of being placed in one-to-one correspondence." That does not mean that the *values* of both sets of data are the same, but that they share the same *structure*.

Comment: @JasonBassford, yes, of course, people who use the phrase *equivalent figures* in this way mean that, even though the figures are different, and thus not equal **in themselves**, there is **some respect** in which they are the same (e.g. they are the results of calculations that have the same structure). Dictionaries permit such use of the word. That's why I did not say that this use of the phrase is incorrect, but only that there is something odd about it. The fact that the alternatives avoid this oddness may be a reason for preferring them.

Answer (score 0):

The Cambridge Online Dictionary defines [counterpart](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/counterpart) as

> a person or thing that has the same purpose as another one in a different place or organisation

This means that 'counterpart' relates people, things or other entities to others of the same type. It does not, usually, relate characteristics of entities to each other.

Also if you look at the definition and examples in the [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/counterpart) entry for 'counterpart' you will see the same thing but with more examples. For instance MW gives the example

> The secretary of defense met with his counterparts in Asia to discuss the nuclear crisis.

That means you could say that "The figures for A's counterpart, B, were between 5 and 15 percent" and use counterpart in its normal way but that talking about "the counterpart figures for B" is definitely not standard.

Jason Bassford's answer includes an Ngram showing that there are a very few cases where the phrase 'counterpart figures' has been used in published work but I would suggest that many, if not all, of those are cases where 'figures' does not mean numbers, or indeed any characteristics of entities. I think they could easily be phrases such as "The great Impressionists and their counterpart figures from the Renaissance" or "The leaders of the Russian revolution such as Lenin and their counterpart figures in the Chinese communist revolution such as Mao"

In a comparison of statistics from two schools the correct term is "equivalent figures".

Comment: I agree right down to the last line. I consider this use of *equivalent figures* an error because the point of the sentence is to *contrast* the figures. You could manage something like "the test scores had different distributions—a score of 80 on test A being equivalent to an 83 on test B." Here, you are equating the scores, not contrasting them.

Comment: @PhilSweet For me and, I believe, in general use the term 'equivalent figures' means the figures which represent the same property of the people, things or organisations to which they refer regardless of the values. For example if person A charges £50 per hour and person B chages £25 per hour for the same job then the cost of using A for a 4 hour job is £200 but the equivalent cost for emplying B is £100. However if A works so fast that he can complete the job in 1 hour but B takes 4 hours then A will cost £50  and the equivalent cost for B will be £100.